# Include class numbering in TOC with a subclass entry when using titlesec and titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, titletoc

I am trying to use titleclass to define two new classes : savoir and subsavoir.

In the TOC, I would like to get something like this :

- Savoir 1 -- First knowkledge title
- Savoir 1.a -- First "subknowledge" of the first knwolege.

I have instead :

- Savoir 1 -- First knowkledge title
- Savoir a -- First "subknowledge" of the first knwolege.

It lacks the **1.** in *savoir 1.a*

Here is a minimal exemple :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}
\titlecontents{savoir}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt\filright}}
  {\contentspush{\bf Savoir \thecontentslabel\ --\ }}
  {}{\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\thecontentspage}
\titlecontents{subsavoir}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt\filright}}
  {\contentspush{\bf Savoir \thecontentslabel\ --\ }}
  {}{\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\thecontentspage}
  \contentsfinish

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{0em}
\makeatother

\titleclass{\savoir}{straight}[\section]
\titleclass{\subsavoir}{straight}[\savoir]
\newcounter{savoir}
\newcounter{subsavoir}[savoir]
\renewcommand{\thesavoir}{\arabic{savoir}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsavoir}{\alph{subsavoir}}
\titleformat{\savoir}[hang]{\large\sf}{Savoir \thesavoir}{0.7em}{#1}
\titlespacing{\savoir}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
\titleformat{\subsavoir}{\large\sf}{Savoir \thesavoir\,\thesubsavoir}{0.7em}    {#1}
\titlespacing{\subsavoir}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Liste des savoirs}
\tableofcontents
\savoir{Premier savoir}
\lipsum[1]
\subsavoir{premier sous-savoir}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: The TOC I get so far]

Thanks

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V), and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is customary to define a hierarchy in terms of the numbering scheme. That is, `\thesubsection` includes part of `\thesection`; `\thesection` includes part of `\thechapter`; and so on. In your case, you're using two different ways of representing the sectioning numbers. Correct these to be uniform:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}
\titlecontents{savoir}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt\filright}}
  {\contentspush{\bfseries Savoir \thecontentslabel\ --\ }}
  {}{\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\thecontentspage}
\titlecontents{subsavoir}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt\filright}}
  {\contentspush{\bfseries Savoir \thecontentslabel\ --\ }}
  {}{\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\thecontentspage}
  \contentsfinish

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{0em}
\makeatother

\titleclass{\savoir}{straight}[\section]
\titleclass{\subsavoir}{straight}[\savoir]
\newcounter{savoir}
\newcounter{subsavoir}[savoir]
\renewcommand{\thesavoir}{\arabic{savoir}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsavoir}{\thesavoir.\alph{subsavoir}}
\titleformat{\savoir}[hang]{\large\sffamily}{Savoir \thesavoir}{0.7em}{#1}
\titlespacing{\savoir}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
%\titleformat{\subsavoir}{\large\sffamily}{Savoir \thesubsavoir}{0.7em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsavoir}{\large\sffamily}{Savoir \thesavoir\,\alph{subsavoir}}{0.7em}{#1}
\titlespacing{\subsavoir}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Liste des savoirs}
\tableofcontents
\savoir{Premier savoir}
\lipsum[1]
\subsavoir{premier sous-savoir}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Above I've commented out the `\subsavoir` title format that *should* be used.

Comment: Thank you really much to both of you Werner and Touhami. It was obvious now that I have the answer, but I have spent a lot of time on this one.

Answer (score 2):

try do this

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsavoir}{\thesavoir.\alph{subsavoir}}
\titleformat{\subsavoir}{\large\sf}{Savoir \thesubsavoir}{0.7em}    {#1}
```

complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}
\titlecontents{savoir}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt\filright}}
  {\contentspush{\bf Savoir \thecontentslabel\ --\ }}
  {}{\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\thecontentspage}
\titlecontents{subsavoir}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt\filright}}
  {\contentspush{\bf Savoir \thecontentslabel\ --\ }}
  {}{\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\thecontentspage}
  \contentsfinish

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{0em}
\makeatother

\titleclass{\savoir}{straight}[\section]
\titleclass{\subsavoir}{straight}[\savoir]
\newcounter{savoir}
\newcounter{subsavoir}[savoir]
\renewcommand{\thesavoir}{\arabic{savoir}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsavoir}{\thesavoir.\alph{subsavoir}}
\titleformat{\savoir}[hang]{\large\sf}{Savoir \thesavoir}{0.7em}{#1}
\titlespacing{\savoir}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
\titleformat{\subsavoir}{\large\sf}{Savoir \thesubsavoir}{0.7em}    {#1}
\titlespacing{\subsavoir}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Liste des savoirs}
\tableofcontents
\savoir{Premier savoir}
\lipsum[1]
\subsavoir{premier sous-savoir}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```